# c program not counting words properly

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, fgets

I have been trying to do a program that will count the number of words from a text file. I have been having problem with counting the words, I decided to create a function to do so because I will do other things with this program (I really want to create a text editor, but I am doing so piece by piece).

The problem is:

My program returns an enormous amount of counted words when I know the text file has a much lower word count. What I am really trying to learn here is how to iterate through characters in an array of strings[I][J].

Additional information:

1. The function that does the counting can print all the strings if I do a simple loop to print all the strings. That means it has passed the strings correctly.
2. I am sending the correct number of lines to the function, I have already double checked.

Here is my code:

Comment: You now make the answer obsolete. That's not how this site works. If initializing `number` did not fix your problem, ask a different question, because not initializing `number` is a very severe mistake and was pointed out in the given answer.

Comment: The line `strings = malloc(...` is allocating 0 bytes, because totalLines is 0.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi sure I can make a new question but it will basically be the same thing, I just thought itd be easier keeping everything in the same place

Comment: `x = realloc(x,...` is unsafe. I suggest using `void* temp = realloc(strings,....); if (temp != NULL) { strings = temp; }`

Comment: @kirkosaur, given that users won't get an alert when you edit the question as opposed to if they're looking to answer questions tagged as you have, you have a better chance of getting a faster answer if you do a new question (since you're the only person getting alerts to this question).

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `number`...that is the problem here in funtion `fWords`.

You are getting an uninitialized value when returning `number` from function `fWords` that's why you get some 'enormous' value.

For logic part word is nothing but one or more letter seperated by whitespaces. So count the gaps between chunk of letters and that will be the desired count.

In `fWord` it will be `for (j = 0; array[i][j] < length; j++)`

Use the `malloc` correctly and check the return value of `malloc` in your case you have used zero value for allocating.

`if(malloc(...)) {//ok ...} else { // not allocated }`

Comment: wow thanks for the quick answer and doh! At least that solves that, now I realize its not actually counting anything

Comment: is the way I iterate through correct? Because i had tried before with an inputted text and it was working correctly with this same logic.

Comment: @kirkosaur Don't you compiler give you warnings?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start here:

```
int  totalLines = 0;
char **strings;
```

and later:

```
strings = malloc (sizeof(char *) * totalLines);
```

What is any number multiplied by zero ;) ?

Why malloc is not null?

> The `malloc()` function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to
>      the allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.  If size is `0`,
>      then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can
>      later be successfully passed to `free()`.

Comment: Many others, like the one before this which caused an edit in the post that invalidated it, and not declaring `fWords()` before `main()` too.

Answer (score 0):

Their are some issues with your code:

- This line:

  ```
  strings = malloc (sizeof(char *) * totalLines);
  ```

  Is basically `strings = malloc(0)`, because you have initialized `totalLines` as `0`. You should instead allocate an initial size such as `totalLines = 10`, then `realloc()` as needed.
- Using `realloc()` like this:

  ```
  strings = realloc(strings, sizeof(char *) * (totalLines ) + 1 );
  ```

  Is dangerous. If `strings` is `NULL`, then you will lose access to `strings`. You can instead do this:

  ```
  void *temp = realloc(strings, sizeof(char *) * (totalLines ) + 1);
  if (temp == NULL) {
      /* handle error */
  } else {
      strings = temp;
  }
  ```

  I also suggest maybe doubling `totalLines`, instead of incrementing it by `1` every time. This is inefficient because you need to `realloc()` after every new line.
- If you decide to use `char content[MAX_LEN + 1];`, then your `fgets()` call needs to be:

  ```
  fgets(content, MAX_LEN + 1, fp)
  ```

  `fgets()` needs the exact number of bytes of the array it points to.
- You can also use `perror()` to get feed back from your OS:

  ```
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
      perror(argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  ```